# I am working in access 2013 and I keep getting a syntax error for the FROM clause

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, SalesRepID
FROM tblCustomer
LIKE "[Cade]", "[Cane]"
ORDER BY CustomerLastName;
```

Comment: `LIKE` is to be used in `WHERE` clause

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the `LIKE` condition in a `WHERE` clause

```
SELECT CustomerID, CustomerFirstName, CustomerLastName, SalesRepID 
FROM tblCustomer 
WHERE [ColumnName] LIKE "Cade" 
 OR [ColumnName] LIKE "Cane" 
ORDER BY CustomerLastName;
```

http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/use-like-criterion-to-locate-data-HA102809506.aspx

Comment: true, except in this particular example OP's `Like`s can be replaced by `=` because there are no wildcards here

Comment: Correct. I just wanted to show him how to use the `LIKE` criterion.